# getting data for specific months from date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a column in MySQL datatable named `added_date`, datatype of it is `varchar(255)` which is inserting date like `mm/dd/yyyy`. I have a lot of data in the table for dates like `'5/12/2018'`, `'4/10/2018'`, `'3/5/2018'`  etc. Now, I want to get data for may, 2018 month only.

How to have the data for may, 2018 only?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL retrieves and displays dates in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. Thus, you have to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert string to date. Then it is possible to use `BETWEEN` keyword in `WHERE` clause to set specific date range:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31';
```

You could [try the query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6tx6TVHJYi3JrbR5aoTavT/3) online.

Comment: The query I proposed (WHERE STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%c%Y') = '52018') is working regardless of the input format. Please see my answer to your comment and please upvote my answer since your comment is not true. Thanks

Comment: Also, the question was not worded the way it is now when I answered. You edited the question !

Comment: Hello, @sam28. 
1. Please read  the question carefully, then open [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6tx6TVHJYi3JrbR5aoTavT/3) and make sure your query doesn't return anything. 
2. In [my edition](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50303046/revisions) I just highlight inline code. The wording was not changed.
3. If you want to reply to commentary of another user, use `@username` instead of posting your reply under another post.

Answer (score -1):

Convert varchar to date within a format that is suitable for your condition:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%c%Y') = '52018';
```

You can use the same function in the select component to return the date too:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS fDate FROM your_table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%c%Y') = '52018';
```

Comment: The `%Y-%m-%d` format corresponds to `2018-12-05` date string. But OP uses another date format.

Comment: The %Y-%m-%d format is just used to display the result in the international date format. the STR_TO-DATE format %c%Y works to filter the data.

Comment: Just try your query within my [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6tx6TVHJYi3JrbR5aoTavT/3) and you will sее the query is wrong.

Comment: @Alexander you are 100% right. For my query to work, it would need to be:SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%c%Y')  = '52018'; which is probably slower than your query. My bad... sorry.